# design an algorithm in pseudocode that will prompt for and receive the measurement for the diameter of a circle and calculate and display th

Tags: javascript

In psuedocode, receive the measurement for the diameter of a circle, calculate and display the aea and circumference of the circle.

Comment: No, we can't tell you how to do this without a more specific description of what exactly your problem is. Please show us your ideas first.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

```
var diameter = 0.0

while(true){
  print "Please enter the diameter of a circle"
  read(diameter)

  if (diameter == 999){
    break
  }

  var circumference = 2 * pi * (diameter/2)
  var area = pi * (diameter/2) * (diameter/2)
  print "Circle area: " + area
  print "Circle circumference: " + circumference
}
```

Comment: Could this be used to determine if a touch is inside a given circle?

Comment: note: this is one of the reasons I'm using SKShapeNode, to detect touches inside the shape, since SKSpriteNode only detects touches inside its rectangle, regardless of the texture content's alpha.